# Reminders.app in IOS5

Tags: ios

I want to add a reminder in Reminders.app (iOS 5+), but I can't find the API. I would also like to ask what the difference between Reminders and iCal is.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no API.

On iOS Reminders stores ToDo items and Calendar stores events or appointments.

On Mac OS, iCal does both. Or at least, it does until Mountain Lion comes out (it splits them up to be more like iOS).